# Countable dense subset claim in Arzela Ascoli proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, rational-numbers, arzela-ascoli

In every Arzela Ascoli proof you see the following:

> Let $S = \mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b]$, where $[a,b]$ is an interval in
>    $\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ is a countable dense subset and there exists a
>   finite number of points $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$ such that $\forall x
>  \in [a,b], |x - x_j| < \delta$, for at least one $j = \{1, \ldots,
>  k\}$

It seems trivially true, since $Q$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But there are some interesting details....

1. there exists finitely number of points $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$ , however $S$ is countable but not finite. What happened to the rest of the points?
2. For at least one $j$...? Why not for all $x_j$ since for every rational we can stick a real in between that is $\delta$ close.

Can someone provide a proof to the claim and resolve the problems?

Comment: I guess you did not get the point of the argument. We want to cover $[a,b]$ with finitely many intervals of length $2\delta$ where the centers are rational numbers. That's it. You can choose the centers to be rational because $S$ is dense.

Comment: I'm not sure what $\delta$ is supposed to be here. But I think you're just using the compactness of $[a, b]$. For any fixed $\delta > 0$, put a ball of radius $\delta$ around each element of $S$. Since $S$ is dense in $[a, b]$, this is an open cover of $[a, b]$, so it can be thinned to a finite subcover. This gives you what you want.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Is Arzela Ascoli do-able if we considered the entire domain instead from the start? I don't understand why we need to first consider a countable dense set, then prove that uniform convergence on dense set holds for the entire domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix some $\delta > 0$. Then  $\{ (q-\delta, q+\delta) \mid q \in \mathbb Q \}$ is an open covering of the compact set $[a,b]$. Therefore, there is a finite subset $\mathcal F \subseteq \{ (q-\delta, q+\delta) \mid q \in \mathbb Q \}$ that also covers $[a,b]$. This in return means that there is a finite set $\{q_1, \ldots, q_n\}$ of rational numbers such that for all $x \in [a,b]$ there is some $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $\mid q_i - x \mid < \delta$.